# How can I pass variable(m_otp) here in my payload

Tags: json, api, postman

```
import requests
import random

m_otp=str(random.randint(100000,999999))
print(m_otp)

url = "https://ziper.io/api/send.php?instance_id=My_instance_id&access_token=My_Acess_token&type=json&number=919XXXXXXXXX"

payload = "{\r\n    \"text\": \"Hello there \"\r\n }"
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I tried solutions from github but there is the thing I'm getting it.

Comment: I am trying to pass a variable I generated randomly in the third line to Payload (6th line).

Comment: What is your output for `print(m_otp)`?

Comment: Please include how you'd expect the payload to be (example) in your question

Answer (score 0):

Do you think of something like:

```py
import requests
import random
import json

m_otp=str(random.randint(100000,999999))
print(m_otp)

url = "https://ziper.io/api/send.php?instance_id=My_instance_id&access_token=My_Acess_token&type=json&number=919XXXXXXXXX"

payload = {"text": "Hello there", "m_otp":m_otp}
payload_str = json.dumps(payload)
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload_str)

print(response.text)
```

?

If not, feel free to tell me the issue and I'll edit my answer.

Also, shouldn't `m_otp` get passed as a `int` ?